# Is there a way to programmatically open a NEW built-in terminal in VSCode from the terminal/bash?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Specifically I'd like to run a terminal command from vscode's built in terminal and have that command open another new vscode built-in terminal. Is this possible?

This is related to my question here - https://github.com/mklement0/ttab/issues/51#issuecomment-1372825316

> Say I have the following command in my package.json scripts:
>
> ```
> "sayHello": "ttab echo hello",
> ```
>
> And I run npm run sayHello from the vscode integrated terminal. Is
> there a way to have it so that the new terminal that is created is
> created within the integrated terminal instead of from (in my case)
> the default mac terminal application?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to include your comment on GitHub as text here because that's customary, but also because it shows that this is not an XY problem.

Comment: Is it not `vscode.window.createTerminal`? I haven't fiddled with the API but it looks promising.

Comment: @vera. is it possible to access that api from the terminal though?